# Переезд с Mysql на Mysqli

Tags: mysql, mysqli

решил переехать на Mysqli с Mysql.
Перечитав несколько статей я понял что сделать это не так уж и трудно. Но скрипт все ровно не хочешь заводиться. 
Красноглазить нет сил, решил поинтересоваться у вас народ, где у меня ошибка.

```html
<?php
 global $config;
 include_once("config.php");
 $config["show_error"] = false;
 $config["encode_key"] = "KEY";
 $config["table_settings"] = "settings";
 $config["table_users"] = "users";
 $config["table_types"] = "types";
 $config["table_categorys"] = "category";

 function db_connection()
 {
  $data_sql = mysqli_connect($config["sql_host"], $config["sql_user"], $config["sql_pass"], $config["db_name"]);
  mysqli_query($data_sql, "SET NAMES utf8");
 }
 function db_close()
 {
  global $data_sql;
  @mysqli_close($data_sql);
 }
 function clean($str)
 {
  $str = @trim($str);
  if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
  {
   $str = stripslashes($str);
  }
  return mysqli_real_escape_string($str);
 }
 function is_login()
 {

  if (isset($_SESSION['userId']) && ($_SESSION['username']) && ($_SESSION['regDate']))
  {
   return true;
  }
  else
  {
   @session_destroy();
   return false;
  }
 }
    function is_login_seller()
 {

  if (isset($_SESSION['userId']) && ($_SESSION['username']) && ($_SESSION['regDate']) && ($_SESSION['userType'] == '3'))
  {
   return true;
  }
  else
  {
   @session_destroy();
   return false;
  }
 }
 function is_login_admin()
 {

  if (isset($_SESSION['userId']) && ($_SESSION['username']) && ($_SESSION['regDate']) && ($_SESSION['userType'] == '1'))
  {
   return true;
  }
  else
  {
   @session_destroy();
   return false;
  }
 }
function sql_error()
{
 if ($config['show_error'])
 {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($data_sql));
 }
 else
 {
  die("Error, please contact webmaster for more information.");
 }
}

 if (!$config['show_error'])
 {
  error_reporting(1);
 }
 session_start();

 db_connection();
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $config["table_settings"];
 $result = mysqli_query($data_sql,$sql);
 if ($result)
 {
  while ($setting = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
   $listSetting[] = $setting;
  }
  if (is_array($listSetting))
  {
   foreach($listSetting as $setting)
   {
    $config[$setting[settingName]] = $setting[settingValue];
   }
  }
  else
  {
   die("Data setting has error.");
  }
 }
 else
 {
  if ($config['show_error'])
  {
   die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($data_sql));
  }
  else
  {
   die("Error, please contact.");
  }
 }
 db_close();
?>
```

Comment: Во все функции пропишите `global $data_sql;` что ли.

Comment: И вместо `mysqli_query($data_sql, "SET NAMES utf8")` используйте метод/функцию для этого предназначенную http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста что за ошибка, разница между `mysqli` И `mysql` толком то и нет, и да, если решили куда-то «переезжать» то лучше уж в `PDO`. :)

Comment: В итоге на странице:
"Error, please contact."